# Windows Dos/Batch File Books

Tags: windows-xp, windows-server-2003, batch-file

I recently moved to a new company that uses Windows batch files left, right and center.

Is there a definitive book of writing / using batch scripts out there? It's mostly Windows XP and Server 2003 in the backend and workstations.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I use good old-fashioned Google for help. The first five links on Google are the main go-to sites I use (depending on which is ranked higher at the time). I used the search `nt batch files`.

Comment: I thought of mentioning the first five google results, but I wasn't sure if those were personalized results due to my having used them in the past.

Answer (score 1):

I learned batch scripting by asking questions on forums and by referencing several sites constantly as I was working my way through a script of my own devising.

The sites I referenced most frequently were:

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchcommands.php

http://ss64.com/nt/

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722477.aspx

http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm

[http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-
us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-)

They are mostly references for commands and their syntax. But that was what I needed and that was what helped me most.